# UITabBarController turns Black while switching tabs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have embedded a **UITabBarController** inside a  UINavigationController. The **UITabBarController** contains 3 different tabs which leads to 3 different **UIViewControllers** which displays UITableView. I implemented all these through storyboard. In the first UIViewController, I have implemented a **UISearchController** for the UITableView programatically which is working. **The View turns black when I search for a particular cell and then if I switch tabs.**
I believe that the issue has some relation to SearchController because before including the SearchController, I didn't have any issues.

I have gone through few other questions in here, but none could solve my issue.

Edited :

Below is my code related to SearchController.

**@interface**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property BOOL searchControllerWasActive;
@property BOOL searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder;
```

**@implementation**

**viewDidAppear()**

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.tblContactsTable.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

**- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController**

```
//reloads table view according to what is searched.
```

**-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar**

```
self.searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: sample code of which part should i share ?

Comment: please apply the below code i answer to your question. i also faced the same problem of black screen

Comment: I created the UITabBarController using StoryBoard and its working without the SearchController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UITabBarController** should be the top most element on window from your storyboard/code and you can add the Navigation Controllers and View Controllers to UITabBarController view controllers.
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/index.html

Comment: Can you please explain that point ? I am very new to programming.

Comment: UITabBarController should be your initial controller. You can follow the given steps for UITabBarController implementation.
**1) Programatically:* http://bcdilumonline.blogspot.in/2014/04/add-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically.html

**2) Storyboard:** https://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 1):

use this sample code it will surely help you here chatlist, contactlist and findfriends are 3 `UIViewControllers`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;

        self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        _chatlist = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChatListVC"];
        _contactlist = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContactListVc"];
        _findfriends = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FindfriendsVC"];

        self.tabbarcontroller = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

        self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_chatlist,_contactlist,_findfriends, nil];


        self.tabBar.frame =CGRectMake(0,44,self.view.frame.size.width,50);

        UITabBarItem *item0 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
        UITabBarItem *item1 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
        UITabBarItem *item2 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];

        item0.title = @"Chat List";
        item1.title = @"Contacts";
        item2.title = @"Find Friends";

        [item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chatlist.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chatlist.png"]];
        [item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"contacts.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"contacts.png"]];
        [item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"findfriends.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"findfriends.png"]];


    }
```

Comment: I believe that the issue has some relation to SearchController because before including the SearchController, I didn't have any issues. I have edited my question with the code example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer myself. I don't know if its the exact right way of doing it but now the App seems working.

I place my UITabBarController as the Initial View and separate UINavigationControllers for each tabs.

Answer (score 0):

When I had such problem, it had helped me.
Please, add this line to viewDidLoad

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```